# tcpdump not working when binding inside snap

Tags: snap, tcpdump

We have a snap and we are binding tcpdump(Since it is custom OS based on  and these cli tools not available by default) from inside our snap, previously for our snap base was core18 and it was working fine but after upgrade to core20 nmap and tcpdump command stopped working.
nmap command we solved by adding

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/usr/lib/$SNAPCRAFT_ARCH_TRIPLET/blas"
```

but tcpdump problem still exist.
When i try to run tcpdump using command

```
my_snap.tcpdump -i any
```

it's throwing error as

```
tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'
```

But same was working before when my_snap was in core18.

**Update**
When i tried with -Z root it is giving below error

```
root@2LK2F92:/home/admin# sudo my-snap.tcpdump -Z root -i any
tcpdump: Couldn't change to 'root' uid=0 gid=0: Operation not permitted
```

Any help folks it is killing me.

Comment: Can you please define **not working**? and give us a little bit more details on which snap package are you using?

Comment: Updated *not working* with error. and it is custom snap which we build

Comment: did you try to spacify the user for tcpdump with **-Z _yourUser_** option

Comment: can you run the command **snap interface network** and verify that your snap package is in the **plugs** section?

Comment: Yes snap interface network is listing my snap in plugs